# Is "ps -ef" deprecrated?

Tags: ps

I was doing some work on a linux and the system admin told me that `ps -ef` is deprecated though it still works.

I can't seem to find any documentation towards the same. Has `ps -ef` really been deprecated?

Comment: Time to upgrade your system admin?

Comment: I use it everyday!

Comment: But remember: Don't talk back to the Sheriff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a huge mistake by your system admin.

`ps -ef` is defined by `POSIX`, you can use it on all systems which are compatible with `POSIX`.

You can see manpage of `ps` by `POSIX` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ps.html).